# Contribution of a change in volume in a liquid to the change in heat capacity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

I have come upon this question that asks me to estimate the contribution of an expansion in a liquid to its heat capacity. However, I do not understand how a change in its volume can affect it's heat capacity. 
Furthermore, after thinking about it for some time and then looking at the solution I have become more confused as it states that what I am looking for is the ratio of the heat absorbed by the sample to the work done by the sample.

I am obviously not understanding something conceptually here so any pointers would be much appreciated.

[image: screenshot of the question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume they take the heat capacity to be constant from 4 to 100 degrees. This sample of water can take up some heat $\Delta Q = c_p m \Delta T  $. So now the question is: what does the heat do to the sample ? For an isobaric process it can increase its temperature and its volume. Both processes contribute to the uptake of the heat, which is described by the former equation. And for an isobaric process we know $dQ = dU +dW$.

Comment: So the question is somewhat strange, it asks what the contribution to the heat capacity. Is this this question the same then as asking 'how does the change in volume contribute to the transfer of heat into the system?''